# Check DB settings --> Variable '<variablename>' is used before it has been assigned a value

Tags: sql, xml, database

I'm writing a simple function that returns me true if my sqlDB connection is ok. I read my DB settings from an XML file and i'm sure this part works because my values (server, database, user, password) get a value assigned after my xml read. When i want to use these variables in my connectionstring is says i'm using them without any value?

```
Public Function TestDBconnection() As Boolean

    'Read settings from XMLfile'
    Dim server, database, user, password As String

    Try
        If System.IO.File.Exists(defaultdirectory & "\Settings.xml") = True Then
            Using XmlSettingsReader As XmlReader = New XmlTextReader(defaultdirectory & "\Settings.xml")
                While (XmlSettingsReader.Read())
                    Dim type = XmlSettingsReader.NodeType
                    If (type = XmlNodeType.Element) Then
                        If (XmlSettingsReader.Name = "Server") Then
                            server = XmlSettingsReader.ReadInnerXml.ToString
                        End If
                        If (XmlSettingsReader.Name = "Database") Then
                            database = XmlSettingsReader.ReadInnerXml.ToString
                        End If
                        If (XmlSettingsReader.Name = "User") Then
                            user = XmlSettingsReader.ReadInnerXml.ToString
                        End If
                        If (XmlSettingsReader.Name = "Password") Then
                            password = XmlSettingsReader.ReadInnerXml.ToString
                        End If
                    End If
                End While
                XmlSettingsReader.Close()
            End Using
        End If

        Using sqlcon As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("server=@server ;uid=@user ;password=@password ;database=@database")
            sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@server", server)
            sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", user)
            sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@database", database)
            sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password)
            sqlcon.Open()
            Return (sqlcon.State = ConnectionState.Open)
            sqlcon.Close()
        End Using
    Catch result1 As SqlException
        Return False

    Catch result2 As Exception
        Return False
    End Try

End Function
```

Comment: Please tag the language (I suppose it's VB.Net)...

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set a stop mark and walk through step by step? What is the programm reading into the XmlReader? What happens at all the `If`?

I'm sure the lines where you set a value to your variables aren't touched at all. Therefore your variables remain not initialized.

Try to set default values to them and you will not get the error you've got before... But you'll have to find out, which variables are not set.

Might be, that there is no file at all...

Comment: Yes I've tested with a stop and even with a messagebox right before the point where i'm creating a new sqlconnection. The messagebox gave me all the values (server,db,user,pass) just like they are set in my xml file. That's the reason why i think it's strange that he keeps telling me that these variables have no value?